# $f(z)= az$ if $f$ is analytic and $f(z_{1}+z_{2})=f(z_{1})+f(z_{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an analytic function with $f(z_{1}+z_{2})=f(z_{1})+f(z_{2})$, how can we show  that $f(z)= az$  where $a$  is a complex constant?

Comment: You should probably specify that (if?) $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb C$

Comment: I'm a little confused why you unaccepted my answer and instead accepted your brother's(?), especially since it's very hard to read and has a few typos. What was it that you were unhappy with my solution?

Comment: @mrf, (my brother???)I think you've a problem with my solution.Pls tell me,I dont want reputation,I want knowledge, so pls tell me what is the problem in my solution,I will remove it.by the way   I've up voted your answer & I think that's quite good & smart.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$f'(z)=\ lt_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=lt_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(z)+f(h)-f(z)}{h}\\=lt_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=lt_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(0)+ \frac{hf'(0)}{1!}+\frac{h^2f''(0)}{2!}+...}{h} $

(by the taylor's series expansion  of $f(h)$
)

$so, f'(z)=lt_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f'(0)}{1!}+\frac{hf''(0)}{2!}+...$

since , $f'(0)$ *is a complex constant,  then*, $f'(z)$ *is constant*. 
Then

$f(z) =az+b$ since $f(0)=0$, then we have that $f(z)=az $

Answer (score 10):

It's true under weaker assumptions, but let's do it by assuming that $f$ is analytic.

Fix $w \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $f(z+w) = f(z)+f(w)$, it follows that $f'(z+w) = f'(z)$ for all $z$. Hence $f'$ is constant, say $f'(z) = a$ which implies that $f(z) = az+c$.

Plug in $z_1 = z_2 = 0$ in the defining equation to conclude that $f(0) = 0$, so $f(z) = az$.

Comment: $f'(z+w) = f'(z)$  FROM THAT   HOW CAN YOU SAY THAT $f'$ IS CONSTANT? @mrf

Comment: @AKASNILCHAKRABORTY The equality holds for every $z$ and every $w$. (For example, choose $w=-z$.)

Comment: please see my proof also, I've a li'le bit confusion on that.
Is it alright??