# show that $f(z)=f(1)z. $

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is entire such that $f(z_1 + z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$ for all $z_1,z_2 \in\Bbb C$,
then show that $f(z)=f(1)z$.

I can see if $f=u+iv$ then for all $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb R^2$

$u(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=u(x_1,y_1)+u(x_2,y_2)$ and $v(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=v(x_1,y_1)+v(x_2,y_2)$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325637

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** You can prove that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}f(1)$ for the positive integers. Then $f(z)-zf(1)$ is an analytic function which is zero at $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$. Since this set has an accumulation point......

Comment: I don't follow this hint. Could you give more explanation?

Comment: @takecare Hint: What does the identity theorem for Analytic functions say?

Comment: We need that two functions are equal in some open neighborhood. How do we get a neighborhood from this?

Comment: @takecare They only need to be equal on a sequence which is convergent in the domain [i.e. the functions must be equal on the sequence and analytic at the limit point].... The open set version is weaker than needs be.